# How do I update a column when the time stamp of another column is less than X amount of hours of current time

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table called Tracker with multiple columns but I really just want to reset one column(status) back to 0 if the time stamp in another column is the current time minus 10 hours.

This is my query

```
update Tracker
set Status = '0'
Where status <> '0' and lastlogintime <= dateadd(HH, -10,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

The time stamp for myself is 15:59 and the actual time right now is 14:51.  If I run this query, it resets my status back to 0 even though 15:59 is greater than 14:51 - 10 hours.  If I change the query to `lastlogintime >= dateadd(HH, -10,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`, it doesn't reset the status back to 0.

Can someone please help me out on this?
Thank you.

Comment: Create an `update trigger`

Comment: I have an update trigger created to update the lastlogintime each time someone logs into the application.  Due to limited licenses, we're trying to run an automated query to run every night at 10pm at night to reset all sessions that have logged in before noon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the value returned by `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is `DATETIME`. You need to do something like

```
CAST(lastlogintime AS TIME) <= CAST(DATEADD(hh, -10, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS TIME)
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked.  I marked the answer as useful but because my rep points are too low it won't show up :(